# Ecto - Preload association when creating record with parent associations

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I receive an error on an Association when creating a child record when passing the ID values of the parent records of a 1 to Many association.

The error says I need to preload `User` which is a parent record to `Transaction`,

```
  1) test creates and renders resource when data is valid (MyRewardsWeb.TransactionControllerTest)
       test/controllers/transaction_controller_test.exs:36
       ** (RuntimeError) attempting to cast or change association `user` from `MyRewards.Transaction` that was not loaded. Please preload your associations before manipulating them thr
  ough changesets
       stacktrace:
         (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset/relation.ex:66: Ecto.Changeset.Relation.load!/2
         (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:514: anonymous fn/4 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.surface_changes/4

         (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1623: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
         (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:503: Ecto.Repo.Schema.surface_changes/4
         (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:186: Ecto.Repo.Schema.do_insert/4
         (my_rewards_web) web/controllers/transaction_controller.ex:20: MyRewardsWeb.TransactionController.create/2
         (my_rewards_web) web/controllers/transaction_controller.ex:1: MyRewardsWeb.TransactionController.action/2
         (my_rewards_web) web/controllers/transaction_controller.ex:1: MyRewardsWeb.TransactionController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
         (my_rewards_web) lib/my_rewards_web/endpoint.ex:1: MyRewardsWeb.Endpoint.instrument/4
         (my_rewards_web) lib/phoenix/router.ex:261: MyRewardsWeb.Router.dispatch/2
         (my_rewards_web) web/router.ex:1: MyRewardsWeb.Router.do_call/2
         (my_rewards_web) lib/my_rewards_web/endpoint.ex:1: MyRewardsWeb.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
         (my_rewards_web) lib/my_rewards_web/endpoint.ex:1: MyRewardsWeb.Endpoint.call/2
         (phoenix) lib/phoenix/test/conn_test.ex:224: Phoenix.ConnTest.dispatch/5
         test/controllers/transaction_controller_test.exs:41: (test)
```

In my controller method, I find `User` and `Merchant` records which are both parent records of the `Transaction` struct and pass the respective record ID's to when creating the changeset

```
  def create(conn, %{"merchant_id" => merchant_id, "mobile" => mobile, "amount" => amount}) do
    customer = MyRewards.find_user!(%{"mobile" => mobile})
    merchant = Repo.get(MyRewards.Merchant, merchant_id)
    changeset = MyRewards.create_deposit_changeset(%{"user_id" => customer.id, "merchant_id" => merchant.id, "amount" => amount })
    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, transaction} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:created)
        |> put_resp_header("location", transaction_path(conn, :show, transaction))
        |> render("show.json", transaction: transaction)
      {:error, changeset} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
        |> render(MyRewardsWeb.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

This function just passes the info along and returns the changeset:

```
 def create_deposit_changeset(user_id: user_id, merchant_id: merchant_id, amount: amount) do
   MyRewards.Transaction.deposit(%MyRewards.Transaction{}, %{ merchant_id: merchant_id, user_id: user_id, amount: Money.new(amount) })
 end
```

In the struct, I have the relationships defined and cast the `user_id` and `merchant_id` correctly as parameters in the `Transaction` Ecto Struct definition.

```
defmodule MyRewards.Transaction do

  @entry_types [:credit, :debit]

  use MyRewards.Model
  schema "my_rewards_transactions" do
    field :amount, Money.Ecto.Type
    field :type, :string
    belongs_to :user, MyRewards.User
    belongs_to :merchant, MyRewards.Merchant

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:amount, :type, :user_id, :merchant_id])
    |> validate_required([:amount, :type])
  end

  def deposit(struct, params) do
    struct
    |> cast( %{type:  "debit"}, [:type])
    |> changeset(params)
  end


  def widthdraw(struct, params) do
    struct
    |> cast( %{type: "credit"}, [:type])
    |> changeset(params)
  end
end
```

When I test the function in my test cases, it enters the transaction fine.

```
MyRewards.create_deposit_changeset(user_id: customer.id, merchant_id: merchant.id, amount: x)
```

But then when I run it in the Phoenix Controller, it fails. I'm not sure why it fails or asks for the preloading of the parent association. Should I be doing a `put_assoc` somewhere instead of casting `user_id` and `merchant_id` directly as parameters?

Comment: only the test fails?

Comment: The test passes but the controller action fails

Comment: check this line: `changeset = MyRewards.create_deposit_changeset(%{"user_id" => customer.id, "merchant_id" => merchant.id, "amount" => amount })`...from your scenario there's no function clause matching, is it correct?

Comment: that was not the issue, but thanks. I had overloaded the function call to accept both types of parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that my setup as an OTP application can not share the preloaded aspect of Ecto. My web side in Phoenix is fine but I cannot commit the changeset in the controller because the `Repo` in the Phoenix app is not the same reference as the changeset that is OTP app, which is causing the preload error.

The reason I had extracted it was due to a `!` i had missed on my original setup.

I changed my controller back to look like this where it returns `{:ok, transaction}` like this

```
case MyRewards.create_deposit(%{"user_id" => customer.id, "merchant_id" => merchant.id, "amount" => amount }) do
  {:ok, transaction} ->
    conn
    |> put_status(:created)
    |> put_resp_header("location", transaction_path(conn, :show, transaction))
    |> render("show.json", transaction: transaction)
  {:error, changeset} ->
    conn
    |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
    |> render(MyRewardsWeb.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
end
```

This is different because I'm not returning the changeset. I'm performing the Repo.insert in the OTP app and returning the transaction.

```
def create_deposit(%{"user_id" => user_id, "merchant_id" => merchant_id, "amount" => amount }) do
  MyRewards.Transaction.deposit(%MyRewards.Transaction{}, %{ merchant_id: merchant_id, user_id: user_id, amount: Money.new(amount) })
    |> MyRewards.Repo.insert
end
```

The original reason why I had changed from this was because I was using `|> MyRewards.Repo.insert!` instead of `|> MyRewards.Repo.insert`.... that `!` bang at the end changes the return of the function to only return the struct instead of returning a status and a struct like `{:ok, transaction}` which is what the controller is expecting.

In short, if you have your Application split into OTP and a Phoenix, watch out for `!` in your repo inserts.